# Equavallent of scan() OR parsing a string for integers in R

Tags: r

In order to get integers from string `"11 22 33"`, in C/C++  we just run function `scan(str, "%n %n %n", &i1, &i1, &i3)` .

How do we do it in R ?

I need to do it to parse the input from `readline("Please enter column indices, separated by SPACE")`

Comment: R has a `scan` function as well. They are probably relatives. Try `scan(textConnection("11 22 33"))`. You can read more about how to help it parse with `?scan`.

Comment: This is the answer too! Tx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the `strsplit()` function which returns a list of each element found from splitting. After than you will want to cast with `as.integer()`.

```
as.integer(unlist(strsplit('11 22 33', split=' ')))
[1] 11 22 33
```

The `unlist()` function simply converts the format of the data from a list to a vector so the integer casting can be done directly on the vector.